# how to run gunicorn with django as non-root

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a django application and I use gunicorn to run it. My script to start gunicorn looks like this:

```
django_path=/path/to/your/manage.py 
settingsfile=my_name  
workers=2 

cd $django_path
exec gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.$settingsfile app.wsgi --workers=$workers &
```

this works when I execute it. However, when I look at my database in my projectfolder `(cd /path/to/your/manage.py && ll)` I get this:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    55K Dec  2 13:33 db.sqlite3`

Which means I need root permisson to do anyhting on the databse (for example do a `createuser`). So I looked around on Stackoverflow and tried a couple of things:

- I had the whole script at the top of  `/etc/init.d/rc.local`
- Then I put the script as a script file `gunicorn_script.sh` put in `/etc/init.d`, did a `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f gunicorn_script.sh defaults`
- Lastly, I tried to put this command at the top of the `rc.local` file: `su debian -c '/etc/init.d/gunicorn_script.sh start'` to execute the gunicorn_script as a debian user

All of them started my app but the problem with the database remains (only root rights).

So how do I run that script as a non root user?

Comment: Hi Paul. This is a nice article about run Django, Nginx, Gunicorn as non-root user: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that `db.sqlite3` will be create in django through the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands which I ran from root.

Hence, the problems with the permissions. I switched to debian and ran the commands from there et voila:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 debian   debian    55K Dec  2 13:33 db.sqlite3`

Answer (score 2):

I have a script in my project's folder which I use to run gunicorn. Here is a header:

```
#!/bin/bash
CUR_DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
WORK_DIR=$CUR_DIR
USER=myusername
PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
GUNICORN=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn

sudo -u $USER sh -c "cd $WORK_DIR; $PYTHON -W ignore $GUNICORN -c $WORK_DIR/config/gunicorn/gunicorn.conf.py --chdir $WORK_DIR myappname.wsgi:application
```

**Updated**:
Put the code below to the file `/etc/init.d/myservice`, make the `root` owner and give `+x` permissions for the owner.

```
#!/bin/bash
#chkconfig: 345 95 50
#description: Starts myservice
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
echo "`basename $0` {start|stop}"
   exit
fi

case "$1" in
start)
   sh /path/to/run_script.sh start &
;;

stop)
   sh /path/to/run_script.sh stop
;;
esac
```

Now you can use `sudo service myservice start`

I am sorry, I am not familiar with `systemd` yet, but with it it can be even easier.

Comment: ok thanks, but it lives in your project folder right? So how do you run it when the system boots? Maybe I forgot to mention that I want the script to run when the system boots?

Comment: Updated the post - added script for init.d

Comment: thanks that helped me with setting up a script for running gunicorn, however I found a different solution to my problem

Comment: You could answer your own question here